# Jhipster springboot angular1.x project with angular 9

Tags: angularjs, jhipster, angular9

Long back we have implemented jhipster springboot project with angularjs 1.5, but now we need to implement new module in angular 9 in the same project. like angular9 and angularJs side by side different apps in same project.

**Project Structure**
[image]

initially calling angularjs templates. while clicking on some button, page navigation, it will redirect to v2_app angular9 application.

> Angularjs route ->  http://localhost:9080/user/#/dashboard
>
> If i click on any navigation it will redirect to v2_app (angular9)
>
> URL should be  http://localhost:9080/user/#/v2/users.

Comment: What is your question? Why do you want to use # in angular 9 routes?

Comment: is it possible to configure angularjs and angular apps in same project with same routing strategy ?

Comment: Probably but wouldn't it be simpler to bundle 2 apps with 2 different index.html? You would avoid dependency hell